# git show last checking when commiting

Tags: git, git-commit

Is it possible to show the text of the last commit when I do a git commit.

I frequently need to check in and associate with a ticket number and I always tend to forget the number and have to go back and do a git log to find out the previous commit and get the ticket id, it would reduce a bit of friction of this was just included in the commit comments that are shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `prepare-commit-msg` hook script to add comments about the most recent commit in the file used for editing the message for the next commit. A basic implementation would be:

```
#!/bin/sh
tmpf=`tempfile`
git show | sed 's/^/# /' > "$tmpf"
cat "$1" >> "$tmpf"
mv "$tmpf" "$1"
```

Comment: is there a way to actually check this hook in as part of the project I'm working on?

Comment: Not directly. Hooks aren't version controlled because they contain code that will be automatically run at various points, and the repository will often receive data from untrusted users. Also, the latest version will often be desired even when working with an old version of the code. You could create the hook in a version controlled portion of the repository, then create a symlink to that in the hooks directory.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can create a post-commit-hook that shows the message log for the last commit (the one recently pushed).

I'd recommend you to read the [Git Hooks section](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) of the Pro Git. It even tells you how to get your last commit (`git log -1 HEAD`), but you probably simply want to `git show HEAD` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You you are on Linux or Mac using git from the command line you could create a shell script called `gitcommit`:

```
git log -1
git commit $*
```

and then use `gitcommit ...` instead of `git commit ...`